# Behavior Changes on SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, migration, compatibility

I'm migrating a SQL Server 2008 database to SQL Server 2019, I have used Microsoft Data Migration Assistant, to look for search any behavior changes, issues or syntax errors.

I have a SELECT that gives me compatibility errors to do the migration:

> Object uses the old style join syntax which can have poor performance at database compatibility level 90 and higher.

This is my SELECT that I think makes the error:

```sql
SELECT 
    @Pro = CEILING((BaseDev * 100) / (ISNULL(BaseExe, 0) + ISNULL(BaseDev, 0)))
FROM 
    (SELECT SUM(Base) 'BaseDev'
     FROM Table1
     WHERE Con = @Con AND Lib <> 0 AND Tip = 1 
       AND Fac = 'V' AND ISNULL(Pct, 0) <> 0) A,
    (SELECT SUM(Base) 'BaseExe'
     FROM Table1
     WHERE Con = @Con AND Lib <> 0 AND Tip = 1 AND Fac = 'V' 
       AND ISNULL(Pct, 0) = 0) B
```

Comment: Do you understand the error? Do you understand how your query works? If we ignore the logic in the derived tables, you are cross-joining "tables" A and B (nice names, btw). So convert it to the newer, less error prone, and more obvious "cross join" syntax.

Comment: What about the error don't you understand here? It *is* using the old style; the `JOIN` is comma delimited.

Comment: The warning about performance is bogus. It makes no difference to performance though there are other reasons to prefer the explicit `CROSS JOIN` syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  SELECT @Pro = CEILING((A.BaseDev * 100) / (ISNULL(B.BaseExe, 0) + ISNULL(A.BaseDev, 0)))
   FROM 
   (
       SELECT SUM(Base) AS BaseDev
        FROM Table1
        WHERE Con = @Con AND Lib <> 0 AND Tip = 1 AND Fac = 'V' AND ISNULL(Pct, 0) <> 0
   ) A
  CROSS JOIN 
   (
       SELECT SUM(Base) AS BaseExe
       FROM Table1
       WHERE Con = @Con AND Lib <> 0 AND Tip = 1 AND Fac = 'V' AND ISNULL(Pct, 0) = 0
   ) B
```

I guess you can replace your query with this one

Answer (score 3):

You could just completely get rid of the `JOIN` and use conditional aggregation:

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Pct <> 0 THEN Base END) AS BaseDev,
           SUM(CASE WHEN Pct = 0 OR Pct IS NULL THEN Base END) AS BaseExe
    FROM dbo.Table1
    WHERE Con = @Con
      AND Lib <> 0
      AND Tip = 1
      AND Fac = 'V')
SELECT @Pro = CEILING((BaseDev * 100) / (ISNULL(BaseExe, 0) + ISNULL(BaseDev, 0)))
FROM CTE;
```

This *should* be more performant too, as it results in a single scan/seek of the table.